# pass file name from logger to appender

Tags: log4j2

i want to log out to different files because there are too many and hard to fallow. For example i have hospital application and i want separate log file for every different action like appointment, reports and patient

```
public org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger logManager = LogManager.getLogger("appointment-log");
public org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger logManager = LogManager.getLogger("reports-log");
public org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger logManager = LogManager.getLogger("patient-log");
```

i can do reports log like below

```
 <appender name="FILE-REPORTS" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${LOGS_HOME}${REPORTS_LOG}</file>
        <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
            <Pattern>
                %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss};%msg%n
            </Pattern>
        </encoder>
        <param name="Append" value="False" />
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <!-- rollover daily -->
            <fileNamePattern>${LOGS_HOME}REPORTS.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log</fileNamePattern>
            <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
                <maxFileSize>100MB</maxFileSize>
            </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
        </rollingPolicy>
    </appender>

    <logger name="reports-log" level="info" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE-REPORTS"/>
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
    </logger>
```

Everything is ok till here but i dont want to write appender for appointment and patient and many more, i want to use only 1 appender then i will pass file name from  , psudo like below

```
<logger name="patient-log" level="info" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="PATIENT-AUDIT" **fileName="patient.log"**/>
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
</logger>
```

Comment: So if a logger is called `/etc/passwd`, you want it to write to the `/etc/passwd` file?

Comment: No i want only 1 appender , n logger, i want to pass log files name from loggers to appender